# Javascript Error on User sign up page

Tags: javascript

I have suddenly started getting these errors on my sign up page:

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) .co.uk/misc/jquery.cookie.js?v=1.0
2. Uncaught TypeError: Object function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} has no method 'cookie' form.js:69

Any ideas what might be causing this...

Comment: It's hard to say, without more info. What modules do you have installed? What scripts do you have running on your signup page? Where and when are you seeing these errors?

Comment: installed modules, http://wequest.co.uk/text.html, scripts: http://wequest.co.uk/scripts.png

Comment: there is only one custom module, and I disabled it, and still getting the error

Comment: read somewhere it might be a server issue with mod_security, so getting them to disable it.

Comment: Have you tried loading the page without scripts and enabling one by one to see which one it's coming from?

Comment: I think that is a good plan. Will try that.

Comment: I'm stupid. The error says it's coming from jquery.cookie.js. Do you know which module adds that file?

Comment: Did you check file permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was rules for mod_security on the server being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to using Autocomplete functions. Disable autocomplete module and Sure error will be gone.

Comment: Nope that wasn't the problem.